# Windows 10 Virtual Box guest on Ubuntu 18.04 host slows down after time, but is fast after starting Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I have the problem described in the question. There was the same question on quora a year back, however, none of the proposed answers - which were more about what might be going wrong than how to repair the situation - did go in any direction that would help me.

My system:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, 64 bit
- 64 GB of RAM
- intel core i7 6700K CPU 4 GHz x 8

I have given 32 GB of RAM and 4 Processors to the virtual machine.

When the ubuntu box is started, the windows guest runs smoothly and fast. 
Over time of the uptime of the ubuntu host, the guest system slows down - in my opinion, this slowing down process is linked to the uptime of the host, not the runtime of the guest.

I checked that:

- RAM consumption on Host and Guest are low (i.e., plenty of ram left on the host and the guest nearly not consuming anything)
- CPU consumption low on Host and Guest

I am working with snapshots that I perform regularly. Making snapshots does not speed up the guest.

I am often completely shutting down the guest and restarting (both using ACPI shutdown and reset). Not speeding up the guest.

I am completely unable to pinpoint why the guest would be slow.

I can provide the VM logs as I am unable to use them myself (I have no idea what I might be looking for).

Any help would be appreciated - note that the obvious "workaround-solution", restarting the host, is not an option as I have long-running processes on that machine that I do not want to interrupt.

Comment: Prescribing a solution without clearly understanding the problem seems unwise. My Windows VM Guest does *not* seem to slow down, running happily and fast day after day.

Comment: *in my opinion, this slowing down process is linked to the uptime of the host, not the runtime of the guest.*  One way to test this hypotheses is to shutdown the VM and starting it again while in the same Ubuntu session. Have you? What were the results?

Comment: I do not have an exact quantification of the slowness of the system. Most of the time, the guest is not running. I only start it sporadically when I need to edit ms office documents or program some VBA. Whe I write that "in my opinion..." I mean that there was a jump in slowness between instances of running the VM (about one week apart). A week ago, the Guest was reasonably fast, now it is not. This behaviour is reproducible, it happened several times (several boots of the Ubuntu host).

Comment: And yet you are of the opinion that the slowness (doesn't matter how much) of the VM Windows *is linked to the uptime of the host* without actually testing it? The test is simple as I suggested above.

Comment: OK, I thought that I _did_ perform the exact test that you suggested. Timepoint A (one week ago): guest is OK. Then shutting down the guest. Timepoint B (now): starting VM with windows guest. Guest is slow

Comment: Of course, during that time, the Host Ubuntu system was continuously running and _not_ restarted.

Comment: If hard disk is set as dynamic, then slow is caused by delays in growing the storage. That is why you should create large fixed disk for a frequently used vm. Also, slowness can be blamed on slow CPU in powersave mode or general business of OS. Remember also Win Updates are making Windows slow for everybody this October.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not see how your points would explain the slowness. A) My hard disk is set to dynamic - but that is the case also when Ubuntu starts. Why would the system get slower during uptime of the linux host? The hard disk is and was set to dynamic. I perform snapshots and restart the machine - still slow. Slowness only goes away when I restart the host.

Comment: B) CPU is mostly idle on Host and Guest, not in sleep mode as far as I can tell. Nothing busy going on neither on the host nor on the guest.

Comment: C) No windows updates are running in the background. Also, if windows updates were to blame, the system should be slow overall, not only after some uptime of the host.

Comment: Just to continue this thread. The problem still exists (virtualbox 6.0.4) and windows host is still painfully (near-unusably) slow. I found many posts complaining about slow guests; I gave it all the accelerations, cpus and others that were requested - still slow VT-x/AMD-v enabled; 16  GB RAM; 2 cores; 2d- and 3d hardware acceleration enabled; 256 MB of video ram; fixed-size virtual disk. Nothing seems to help. Any advice appreciated.